# Oracle join to get max data and a non-grouped column

Tags: oracle

Consider this part of my query:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, ...

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT field1, field2, MAX(field3) field3
    FROM table
    WHERE field2 IN ('1','2','3','4')
    AND field4 > SYSDATE - 365
    GROUP BY field1, field2) jointable ON other.fk= jointable.field1
```

So `field4` is a date. I need the date from `table`. If I add it to the select list I must add it to the group by and as such it will no longer be grouped in a way to pull the `MAX(field3)`.

I could join `table` again on their primary keys but that doesn't seem ideal. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to speak of selecting `field4` from the subquery when an aggregation is happening.  Your only options are to select an aggregate of `field4` (e.g. min, max), or to add it to the `GROUP BY` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [the aggregate `keep dense_rank` sytnax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm#SQLRF00641) to get the date associated with the maximum `field3` value for each `field1/2` combination:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, ...

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT field1, field2, MAX(field3) field3,
        MAX(field4) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY field3) field4
    FROM table
    WHERE field2 IN ('1','2','3','4')
    AND field4 > SYSDATE - 365
    GROUP BY field1, field2) jointable ON other.fk= jointable.field1
```

Quick demo of just the subquery, with a CTE for some simple data, where the highest `field3` is not on the latest `field4` date:

```
with your_table (field1, field2, field3, field4) as (
  select 'A', '1', 1, date '2016-11-01' from dual
  union all select 'A', '1', 2, date '2016-09-30' from dual
)
SELECT field1, field2, MAX(field3) field3,
  MAX(field4) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY field3) field4
FROM your_table
WHERE field2 IN ('1','2','3','4')
AND field4 > SYSDATE - 365
GROUP BY field1, field2
/

F F     FIELD3 FIELD4    
- - ---------- ----------
A 1          2 2016-09-30
```

Comment: I don't know what that is/does but it worked wonderfully. I knew there was a better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a window function would work well here...

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, ...

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT field1, field2, MAX(field3) over (partition by field1, field2) field3, Field4
    FROM table
    WHERE field2 IN ('1','2','3','4')
    AND field4 > SYSDATE - 365
    GROUP BY field1, field2, field4) jointable ON other.fk= jointable.field1
```

Max of field 3 will now be independant of field 4 but still be dependant on fields 1 and 2.